# How to configure Alpine to use an already running Emacs as an alternate editor?

Tags: emacs, alpine-mail, emacsclient

I have activated in Alpine email client the following setting in order to use Emacs as an editor when composing emails:

```
[X]  Enable Alternate Editor Implicitly
Editor = emacsclientw.exe -ca runemacs.exe
```

When I put the cursor in the body field of message, Emacs opens. But the problem is returning the contents of the Emacs buffer to Alpine. When I save the temporary buffer and return to Alpine, the typed text does not appear in Alpine.

If I use the below settings, Alpine returns the content of Emacs buffer to Alpine, but the problem is that this opens a new instance of Emacs that I dislike.

```
[X]  Enable Alternate Editor Implicitly
Editor    = emacs.exe
```

Comment: I use the latter setup. I actually like that composing messages does not interfere with my programming work in emacs server.

Comment: (Your first and preferred option) After saving in emacs did you do "C-x #"? Or did you just click alpine window?  Also before starting alpine try starting emacs as daemon:  "emacs.exe --daemon"

Comment: @Rusi Thank you, your comment solves the problem. Feel free to convert your comment into an answer, it may help other too.

Comment: Glad to be of help @Name. Do note that you got your help after more than a month! And (from my pov) by fluke because I just landed here by chance. At [emacs se](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) you would get many more experts looking (I think)

Comment: @Rusi The reason I posted the question here was that there are more questions about `alpine  email client` on superuser than emacs se.

Comment: Sure thing: alpine calling out to emacs: is that more alpine or more emacs? You decided it's alpine. It turns out that you accepted my answer which was on the emacs side. Doesn't change the fact that I know little of windows and nothing of alpine More seriously on emacs-se better experts could likely improve my answer. Eg Should you use daemon or fg-daemon?? No idea (for windows). Problem is client-server (daemon) emacs is a strange beast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Your first and preferred option)

After saving in emacs did you do "C-x #"? Or did you just click alpine window? Also before starting alpine try starting emacs as daemon:

```
 emacs.exe --daemon
```